# looking for a better way to get a count-per-city

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Im trying to get a count on how many people live in a certain city. I have a database with people in it, and that table has a foreign key linking a certain person to a city, which is another table.

example:

### City z: 5 people

### City y: 10 people

### City x: 4 people

im able to get these results back, but i just dont like the way i'm doing it, as i am calling the database x amount of times.

```
 public List<int> getStuff(List<int> listOfCityIDs )
    {
       var returnList = new List<int>();
       foreach (int z in listOfCityIDs)
        {
             returnList.Add((from x in conn.people
                             where x.city == z
                             select x).Count());
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

im pretty sure there's a better/more efficient way of doing it with some LINQ, but i can't seem to find how.

any ideas?

kind regards,
Jane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will translate into SQL statements nicely.

```
conn.people.GroupBy(p => p.city).Select(p => new { City = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
```

This will get them all. If you want based for certain cities, try

```
conn.people.Where(p => listOfCityIDs.Any(c => c == p.city))
  .GroupBy(p => p.city).Select(p => new { City = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
```

Comment: its not the same,  there's a set of ids which represent the cities to count

Comment: ie, needs the WHERE clause :)

Comment: does the entity frameworks linq provider know how to take the list of ints and turn it into sql?

Comment: yeah, in which case you could do it after querying the database. But not sure if the EF will be able to translate that into SQL

Comment: thanks, this does what i want indeed. But is this approach more efficient in terms of database load?

Comment: yes it is. it should only translate into 1 sql statement instead of n-number.

Comment: @KeithNicholas it will convert this into a 'WHERE IN' clause

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a cleaner syntax and it works as deferred query

```
var g = from c in cities
    join p in people
    on c equals p.CityId
    group p.CityId by p.CityId into grouped
    select new { CityId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq will optimize this for you when you are calling .Count() It realizes you don't want the whole result set.

Also remember if you are hitting a database (which I assume you are) the result set is an IQueryable which doesn't get executed until you try and get a value from it.

Comment: When you put each item into a list, the result set is a list.

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping people by city id?